# Haskell | Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function myAny

Tags: haskell

I have just started learning haskell and wrote a customized code for any function. 
Please suggest why does it still shows Non-exhaustive patterns error even after I have used otherwise or where I am going wrong?

Exceptiom raised :- 
    Exception: main.hs:(37,1)-(40,21): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myAny

```
myAny :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny f (x:xs)
  | f x == True = True
  | f x == False = myAny f xs
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: And as it was said many times before: if you compile your code with `-W` flag you'd get a warning about it during the compilation instead of runtime error. The warning even tells you exactly what is missing: `Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive     In an equation for 'myAny': Patterns not matched: _ []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that haskell cannot deconstruct `[]` into `(x:xs)`, resulting in the case of an empty list not being covered.

A solution would be to specify:

```
myAny :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny f (x:xs)
  -- ...
myAny f [] = False
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the exact error. Now I got why even after using otherwise, my code wan't considering the case with an empty list.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to implement a clause for the empty list. Since you perform recursion, if none of the elements match, it will eventually call `myAny` with the empty list. In that case you need to return `False`:

```
myAny :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny _ [] = False
myAny f (x:xs)
  | f x == True = True
  | f x == False = myAny f xs
  | otherwise = False
```

Note that it however makes no sense to perform two checks with `f x`, if it is not `True`, it is `False`, so the `otherwise` case will normally never occcur:

```
myAny :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny _ [] = False
myAny f (x:xs)
  | f x = True
  | otherwise = myAny f xs
```

We can further simplify this with [**`(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-124--124-) to:

```
myAny :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
myAny _ [] = False
myAny f (x:xs) = f x || myAny f xs
```

or use a `foldr` pattern:

```
myAny :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
myAny f = foldr ((||) . f) False
```

Comment: If the short `foldr` version looks confusing, note that it's equivalent to `foldr (!!) False . map f`. `f` will be applied to values in the list as necessary, until `f` returns `True` or `foldr` exhausts the list.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution. Also, I used otherwise for any cases left, but it turn out it doesn't considers the case where the list is empty.